# "Traveller" vs. "traveler"

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, doubled-consonants

There was a time when *traveller's cheques* were emitted and sold by the banks in England and by Thomas Cook. However the cheques emitted by American banks/American Express were named *traveler's cheque*, with a single L. I have always wondered why. My English dictionary only has *traveller* with two Ls.

Comment: Traveller is British English,  traveler is American  English

Comment: And those pesky Americans even had the temerity to call them _checks_.

Comment: It's the same reason that Americans say _tomato_ and Brits say _tomato_. Oh, wait.

Comment: You may find this link useful.http://www.tysto.com/uk-us-spelling-list.html